# When trying to access Bios it stays on opening... but doesn't open, windows works fine

Tags: boot, bios, dualboot

I just installed KDE-Neon Linux as dual boot, after installing I tried to restart my computer and open the boot menu to boot into the same OS. But this failed and the boot menu was stuck on opening... for 10 minutes so I stopped it.

After that I tried to access the bios, but awkwardly the same happened. It was just on opening all the time.

What I tried:
Removing all my peripherals and trying again
Restarting several times
Trying out to press esc (same result)
Trying to press f10, f2,... (same result)

Specs:
HP laptop,
Intel core i5 processor,
512GB SSD,
Nvidia MX130,
8 GB RAM,
UEFI System,
Currently working operating system: Windows 10 Home

Comment: If Windows is booting using UEFI, maybe try holding down Shift while clicking the Reboot button. From the menu that appears, you can go to the firmware settings—does that work?

Comment: I forgot to mention, this works, but none of the options except system diagnostic work. On system diagnostics all checks pass, but when trying to open boot menu or bios it unfortunately opens in a black screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself after asking in 10 online forums and no one answering...

If you cannot access your bios, nor windows, you need a USB stick and a separate PC.
On that pc you need to download a (in my case - HP) BIOS recovery USB stick.

Then you stick the USB stick into your broken computer, hold Win+B, then hold the power button for 1-3 seconds and release it, but keep Win+B held.

After a maximum of 60 seconds the HP BIOS recovery environment from your stick should open and automatically reinstall your BIOS without loosing any data.